# Docker compose v3: The difference between volume type mount and bind

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using `docker-compose` syntax version 3 and want to use some volumes. The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-2) on the long syntax for volumes states the following:

> `type`: the mount type `volume` or `bind`

but never fully explains the difference. What is it?

Comment: Has that documentation changed since 2017 or am I just too stupid to find the mentions of "type" as "volume" or "bind"? (I've got some old docker-compose files and am trying to understand the contents.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`bind` is the simpler one to understand. It takes a host path, say `/data` and mounts it inside your container, say `/opt/app/data`. `/data` can be anything, probably mounted on `NFS` or it maybe a local host path.

`docker run -v /data:/opt/app/data -d nginx`

`volume` mount is where you can use a named volume.

You would normally use a volume driver for this, but you can get a host mounted path using the default local volume driver something like the below:

`docker volume create data
docker run -d -v data:/opt/app/data nginx`

The named volume can also be anonymous if you run just this:

`docker run -d -v /opt/app/data nginx`

If you run `docker volume ls`, docker would have create an autogenerated long name for the anonymous volume.

In docker-compose, you would just use it as below:

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  volumes:
    /data:/opt/app/data
    data:/opt/app/data1

volumes:
  data:
```

Comment: Is it configured further in the lower part?
`volumes:
     data:`

Comment: I had a hard time find the difference between volume and bind types of mount. Th reason I was searching for it was the Jenkins Docker image, where the jenkins_home folder is mounted as a volume. The folder was full of data, but that data came from within the image itself. When I tried to bind a host folder, it was empty so jenkins failed. The main difference in my opinion is that the volume can be populated with data when the container is created from image and the bind is just a mount to inject data to container. And that a volume is created by image, bind is at users will.